# How to update a listview from another thread

Tags: c++, multithreading, winapi, c++11

In my win32 application I'm filling a list-view with sparse information (all items, but basically only consisting of a label) in the main thread. After that I want to start reading images and text files from disc and update the corresponding items. This should be done in a separate thread (`std::thread`) as it takes quite a long time to generate thumbnails from the images and parse the whole text files.
I already tried to update the image-list of the list-view directly from the additional thread, but when I try to retrieve a pointer to the image-list through `ListView_GetImageList()` the application crashes.
So I guess it's a better idea to somehow pass the new data back to the main thread and invoke an update. Is there any suggested way to do that in this context?

**Update:**
This is the code I have so far using the approach suggested by ScottMcP-MVP. It's causing an infinite loop after calling `SendMessage()`:

```
#define WM_UPDATE_THUMBNAIL (WM_APP + 1)

void loadThumbnail(HWND hwndMain, size_t index, std::string file)
{
    HBITMAP thumbnail = GenerateThumbnail(file, THUMBNAIL_WIDTH, THUMBNAIL_HEIGHT);
    SendMessage(hwndMain, WM_UPDATE_THUMBNAIL,  (WPARAM)thumbnail, (LPARAM)index);
}

bool UpdateListView(HWND hwndMain)
{
    HWND listview = GetDlgItem(hwndMain, IDC_BROWSE_LIST);
    if (!listview) return false;

    // clear previous data
    ListView_DeleteAllItems(listview);
    ImageList_Destroy(ListView_GetImageList(listview, LVSIL_NORMAL));

    // create a new image list
    HIMAGELIST imageList = ImageList_Create(THUMBNAIL_WIDTH, THUMBNAIL_HEIGHT, ILC_COLOR24, nItems, 1);
    ListView_SetImageList(listview, imageList, LVSIL_NORMAL);

    // add all items with label only
    for (size_t iItem = 0; iItem < items.size(); ++iItem) {
        LVITEM lvItem;
        lvItem.iSubItem = 0;
        lvItem.state = 0;
        lvItem.iItem = (int)iItem;
        lvItem.mask = LVIF_TEXT;
        lvItem.pszText = items[iItem].label;
        lvItem.cchTextMax = 256;
        ListView_InsertItem(listview, &lvItem);
        std::thread t(loadThumbnail, m_hWnd, iItem, items[iItem].thumbnailFile);
    }
    return true;
}

INT_PTR CALLBACK DialogProc(HWND hWnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch (message) {
        // ...
        case WM_UPDATE_THUMBNAIL: {
            // this block is never reached
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: [SendMessage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/ms644950%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). It's safest to only do UI stuff from the UI thread... the one with the message pump. Using `SendMessage` will allow you to do this. Also, it would help to have an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to show what you've tried.

Comment: You need two ingredients to solve this: `1` Use a [Virtual List-View](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb774735.aspx#Virtual_ListView_Style). This makes sure that your list view control is displayed immediately, without waiting for data to arrive. `2` Post a custom message from your worker thread to the thread owning the list view control, and invalidate the respective client area from there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define a custom Windows message and send the address of the new data in the WPARAM or LPARAM of the message:

```
#define WM_MY_MSG (WM_APP + 2) // In a shared .h file

NewData nd;  // In the worker thread
SendMessage(hwndMain, WM_MY_MSG, (WPARAM)&nd, NULL);
```

You will need to initialize the worker thread with hwndMain, which should be the HWND of the listview's parent window. That parent window handles the message and copies the data to the control.

Comment: Somehow I get an endless loop with this approach. I just defined a function `loadFile(HWND hwnd)`, which calls `SendMessage(hwnd, WM_UPDATE_THUMBNAIL,  (WPARAM)0, (LPARAM)0)` and created a new thread from the main thread like this: `std::thread t(loadFile, m_hWnd);`

Comment: The objective is to send data to the main thread, but you are not doing that. Why pass two zeroes? You can edit your question to show enough code that maybe we can see what else you are doing wrong. With the worker thread passing data and the main thread putting the data into the control there is no reason it should become an endless loop.

Comment: Sorry the two zeroes were just for testing. I just extened my post by some code.